# How to increase Magento site speed in Godaddy shared hosting?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, godaddy

I m using a Godaddy shared hosting server for my magento store. It takes a too long response from the server. I optimized the magento site with the default options like,

1. Enable cache in back end
2. Enable compiler
3. Merging Css/Js
4. Leverage browser cache
5. Image optimization etc.

But there is no improve my site performance. My website url is http://fleafashions.com

I need to optimize anything in my site or it is an issue from godaddy?

Comment: The quickest way would be to move off of GoDaddy and choose a hosting provider that supports Magento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your server is dedicated then you install

APC(Alternative PHP Cache) http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Or

you can set the memcache in your server http://www.php.net/memcache.

It will definitely improve your magento Site Speed.

Comment: OP indicates he is talking about a shared plan.

Answer (score 2):

I have a strong belief that most Magento performance problems are caused by poor coding.

Switch to default theme, disable all custom modules and make sure you don't have core overrides. If this will make site work faster then think about refactoring your theme/extensions.

Comment: I agree with this, but Magento really is a resource hog. Depending on his neighbors and the size of his site, shared hosting just might not work for him.

Comment: Magento always punishes the site owner who refuses to give it the resources it needs to run. Refusal to acknowledge this in your business plan is a plan for failure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, Magento hosting should be 0.5-1% of revenue so you will make no revenue with that setup, not much more to say really but go with a good specialised host.

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default needs quite some resources. I took a look at the godaddy hosting page but it doesn't mention the amount of CPU or RAM memory you can use but my best guess is it's way to low to actually run a Magento installation on it.

There is only so much you can optimise, at one point you'll have to scale up the hosting and in that case I would look for a dedicated/VPS solution.

Comment: From experience: If you DO NOT give Magento adequate resources and properly optimize those resources to run it, Magento will punish you by turning into the biggest WOMBAT you’ve ever come across. (WOMBAT - military term for Waste of Money, Brains and Time).